# Lexical or Preprocessor issue Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, swift, lexical

I using  Quickblox

I could successfully install all the pod files,
When Build the project getting error.

```
#import<Quickblox/Quickblox.h>
'Quickblox/Quickblox.h' file not found
```

Also added Framework in the 'Embedded Binaries' section

Comment: Please add screenshot of your resolved "Header search paths" and "Framework search paths" build settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.!!!

I imported the framework in `Swift-Bridge` file.